# Input 0 of layer dense is incompatible with the layer: expected axis -1 of input shape to have value 784 but received input with shape (None, 14)

Tags: python, pandas, tensorflow, keras, kaggle

please help me out in this. Thank you

Please check out the pic for more info on coding https://i.stack.imgur.com/fw5qW.jpg

So bear with me...Also please help if you know the solution. Thank you

import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import tensorflow as tf

```
from google.colab import files
uploaded = files.upload()

import io
df=pd.read_csv(io.BytesIO(uploaded['heart.csv']))

df

df.isna().sum(axis="rows")

from tensorflow.keras.utils import to_categorical

df.shape

y=df["cp"]

x=df.drop("cp",axis="columns")

y=to_categorical(y)

y.shape

x=pd.get_dummies(x,columns=["sex"])

x

df.hist(figsize=(10,10))
plt.show()

mnist = tf.keras.datasets.mnist

(x_train,y_train), (x_test,y_test) = mnist.load_data()
x_train, x_test = x_train / 255.0, x_test / 255.0

from keras.layers import Dense , Flatten
from keras.models import Sequential

model = tf.keras.models.Sequential([
        tf.keras.layers.Flatten(input_shape=(28,28)),
        tf.keras.layers.Dense(128,activation='relu'),
        tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.2),
        tf.keras.layers.Dense(10)])`

loss_fn = tf.keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits=True)

model.compile(loss=loss_fn,optimizer="adam",metrics=["accuracy"])

model.fit(x_train,y_train,epochs=1000)

x

data=pd.DataFrame({"age":[50],"trestbps":[120],"chol":[350],"fbs":[1],"restecg":[1],"thalach":[150],"exang":[0],"oldpeak":[1.5],"slope":[1],"ca":[0],"thal":[2],"target":[1],"sex_0":[0],"sex_1":[1]})

data

model.predict(data)
```

My teacher used this cmds in jupyter but it doesnt work...it lit shows error...tried this in both colab n jupyter...

```
from keras.utils import to_categorical

y=to_categorical(y)

y.shape

X=X.drop(["PassengerId","Name","Ticket"],axis="columns")

X

X=pd.get_dummies(X,columns=["Sex"])

from keras.layers import Dense
from keras.models import Sequential

model=Sequential()
model.add(Dense(32,activation="relu",input_shape=(7,)))
model.add(Dense(2,activation="softmax"))

model.compile(loss="categorical_crossentropy",optimizer="adam",metrics=["accuracy"])

model.fit(X,y,epochs=10)

X

data=pd.DataFrame({"Pclass":[3],"Age":[84],"SibSp":[0],"Parch":[1],"Fare":[7],"Sex_female":[0],"Sex_male":[1]})

data

model.predict(data)

#Output array([[0.9702792 , 0.02972085]], dtype=float32)
```

Comment: You trained a model on MNIST, what makes you think you can predict on your data which is completely different from MNIST data? It makes no sense.

Comment: then what do i do dude? can u tell me the solution from mnist...cause idk what else to use apart from mnist...what my teacher taught doesnt work

Comment: @Dr.Snoopy please provide solution if u do know...Thank you

Comment: If your code shows an error, you need to tell us which error and where, we cannot guess errors.

Comment: https://imgur.com/gallery/DMQmdY2 @Dr.Snoopy  ive used ```tensorflow.keras.utils import to_categorical``` instead of ```from keras.utils import to_categorical``` cause it showed error n upon googling it said keras.utilis doesnt work anymore...have to add tensorflow ahead

Comment: Your input shape should be (14,), not (7,).

Answer (score 1):

Looking at your teacher's python code, the error is telling you that the Dense layer is expecting in input data with 784 features but got a series of data with only 14 features.

By looking at your python code, I'm assuming that you're using the predefined dataset **MNIST** in the teacher's code which, if I remember correctly, the input data in x_train has a shape of (784,x) where x is an integer number that could be 3,4, etc.

Now to solve this problem, you have to understand how you have to pass the data into your model. Looking again at your teacher's code we have this:

```
from keras.layers import Dense
from keras.models import Sequential

model=Sequential()
model.add(Dense(32,activation="relu",input_shape=(7,)))
model.add(Dense(2,activation="softmax"))
```

So we have a Sequential model that has two layers:

- The first Dense node, that works also as the **Input Layer** for the model, is made of 32 units with the Rectified Linear Unit as the activation function and, the most important thing, we know that the **Input shape** of this model is written as a tuple of (7,). So what is this value (7,)? Basically you're telling to the model that your input data has **7 features** so each single data must have 7 values within it.
- The second Dense node is simply the output layer which gives in output a probability answer between two values. This is less important since your problem is passing the input data.

Now to understand how the data is handled in Keras/Tensorflow you have to think the data represented as a matrix where in the rows you have the values of the data while the columns indicates the meaning of the values. Kinda like Excel/CSV files where there is a header which explains the meaning of values in each column.

If you ever used NumPy, more specifically *dimensional arrays*, basically the **shape** of the data is the most important thing you should check before giving the data to your model because the shape tells to you how the data is handled and in how many dimensions is the data represented. If your data has, for example, a shape of (784,14) the data is represented as a bidimensional (2D) matrix where the first value (784) are the rows of the matrix while the second value (14) are the columns.

So to answer your question, the python program is expecting in input a series of data of 784 features, which to me is translated to 784 columns, but instead you have given in input a series of data with only 14 features. So to solve this problem you have to check the shape of your data, which you can simply do with `x_train.shape` and see in output what you get. Next you have to pass correctly the data to the model and then your program will work for sure. One way could be reshaping the data.

For a better understanding of how Tensorflow handles the shape of the data look at this [guide](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/tensor?hl=en).

Another thing I suggest to you is to write your question in a more appropriate way. My suggestion is to write a question in the following way:

- Title of the problem.
- Description of the problem.
- Show the error you get.
- Write what have you tried, add also references to other similar questions from yours.
- ALWAYS show at least one piece of code so people can analyze it. More pieces of codes are also acceptable.
- Optionally, write what is the expected result you want.

If you write the questions in this way surely people will understand better your problem.

I hope this helps understand better your problem.